# jQueryUI Date Picker showing on form submit in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

I am using the jQueryUI Date Picker on one of my forms and if you select the field that I have attached the datepicker to, then select a date, then click "Submit" it should submit the form - which it does in IE but not in Chrome.

In Chrome, it re-opens the date picker and I have no idea why.  I've put the following on pastebin to show the bug;

http://pastebin.me/6889d234b1b426ae2d0ed23cc3d77e39

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening - it's been driving me mad!?

Cheers

Comment: Which version? I'm not seeing it in Chrome 5.0.375.127 here

Comment: Are you sure? I'm with Chrome 6.0.490.1 and it just submits the form and doesn't re-open the date picker.

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome 5.0.375.70.  Just had a friend test it and same happens to him!

Comment: Chrome 5.0.375.127 fails for me on Mac OS X

Comment: @Webbo It is probably a bad in Chrome. Maybe you should have a hack and bind something like that: $('form').submit(function(){ $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide(); });

Comment: @IgalSt - all that will do is close the div, it still doesn't fix the issue of the submit button not firing properly.  This is wierd - how do you download version 6 of Chrome anyway?

Comment: @Nick Craver - are you selecting a different date using the datepicker?  The bug only occurs after you've selected a different date.

Comment: @Webbo I was sure that the submit is being fired but the datepicker re-opens. Anyway, you can download Chrome 6 beta from here: http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOH.  After much testing I found that it wasn't working in Chrome because the attribute "maxlength" was set to 8 and the date field DD/MM/YYYY was 10 characters so Chrome must have been throwing a wobbler at that.

I'm so annoyed with myself.

Comment: Make sure JQuery validation isnt included in your layout and actually trying to validate this in US format. That was the problem for me,and I ultimately had to overload the validation for the datepicker.